# A problem about the incircle and excircle

Tags: geometry

I have tried many ways, including denote a tangent point $F'$ and prove $F'\equiv F$ or denote the points at which the incircle touches the sides but I can't go further. Can someone help me in this problem?

The incircle (its center is point $I$) of $\Delta ABC$ touches the side $AB$ at point $D$. Point $E$ is the reflection of point $D$ with respect to point $I$. Let $AB \cap CE = \{F\}$. Prove that $F$ is the tangent point of the side $AB$ and the $C$-excircle of $\Delta ABC$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Questions showing no effort tend to be voted down

Comment: What is the source? (This is a standard exercise in EGMO, with sufficient hints I think)

Comment: @DS I was given this problem by my teacher. And I don't know about the EGMO you have said about.

Comment: Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads, it's a nice book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the center of $C$-excircle be $J$. Then $C$, $I$, $J$ all belong to one line (the bisector of angle $C$). The point $E$, being symmetric to $D$ with respect to $I$, belongs to the incircle. Consider the homothety with center in $C$ and coefficient equal to the ratio of $C$-excircle and incircle radii.

The tangent line to the incircle, going through $E$, becomes $AB$. So $E$ becomes $F$. The incircle becomes the $C$-excircle. Hence $F$ is indeed the tangent point of the $C$-excircle.

—-

The same reasoning in terms of similar triangles.

We can see that $CI:CJ = r:R$, where $R$ is the radius of the $C$-excircle and $r$ the radius of the incircle. Just drop perpendiculars $II’$ and $JJ’$ from $I$ and $J$ to the line $CB$ and consider similar triangles $CII’$ and $CJJ’$.

As we already know, $E$ is the point of the incircle. Let’s draw a tangent line through it. $B’$ will be the intersection of it and $BC$.

The following holds: $CB’:CB = CI:CJ$. Indeed, $FB \parallel EB’$. $BJ$ and $B’I$ are bisectors, so $BJ \parallel B’I$. From the similar triangles $CIB’$ and $CJB$ we have $CB’:CB = CI:CJ$.

From the similar triangles $CEB’$ and $CFB$ we have $CE:CF = CB’:CB$.

Now consider the triangles $CIE$ and $CJF$. They have a common angle $C$, and also $CE:CF = CB’:CB = CI:CJ$. So they are similar. We have $IE:JF = CI:CJ = r:R$. Knowing that $IE=r$, we get $JF=R$. That means that $F$ is the tangent point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I haven't studied about the transformation in geometry. May I ask for a solution with some basic tenniques?

Comment: @imagerr Are you familiar with similar triangles? Homothety is pretty much the same. It’s just another way to say things, if we consider the school level problems.

Comment: I see. Is the ratio of C-excenter and incircle radii needed if we use similar triangles?

Comment: @imagerr I have edited my answer to add the reasoning in terms of similar triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your statement?

I've tried to draw the situation and in my case, the point $F$ is located somewhere between points $A$ and $B$, so it can't be tangent to a circle, containing those points:

[image]

Comment: C-excircle doesn’t contain A and B. Are you confusing with the circumcircle?

Comment: May be the way I rewrote the statement makes some confusion, I've edited the problem in order not to make any misunderstanding.

Comment: @Aig: yes, I am. Hence my drawing can be used as an illustration of the problem (or how even a mistake can prove to be useful) :-)